# jpeg images in STM32 internal flash

Tags: stm32, flash, imageprocessing, oled

I'm using both STM32F103 and STM32F407 with a SEPS525 SPI driven OLED display (160x128). I want to store images to display in internal flash, but BMP uncompressed images with 16bit colors are huge (about 40kB each). Is it possible to transfer jpeg images in the internal flash and use them with TJpegDec http://elm-chan.org/fsw/tjpgd/00index.html to save some flash space? (I'm using IAR Ide and ST-Link v2)

Many thanks

Comment: Generally you'll use an SD card to store the images, like many of the LCD screens have

Comment: It might be easier to just implement some lossless compression, like RLE or perhaps bzip2 to compress the raw bitmaps. Given you have sufficient memory to decompress images in one chunk, you should be able to get a decent amount of flash savings this way without compromising on quality.

Comment: @TristanSeifert thanks, are there embedded sized libraries for them or some detailed instructions to implement them? It would be good if I can save half of the space compared to uncompressed BMPs.

Answer (score 3):

> are there embedded sized libraries for them or some detailed
>   instructions to implement [lossless decompression]?

Yes, it is possible to put compressed photographs (or drawings or fonts) in flash and then decode them with a variety of libraries.

Two popular techniques for storing arbitrary binary data in flash are: are:

- Store the (possibly compressed) drawings (or photographs or fonts) in a SD card or some other external flash media, and use library functions in your application to pull those images from the card
- Use a bin2hex utility such as xxd[(a)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707183/script-tool-to-convert-file-to-c-c-source-code-array)[(b)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2header/)[(c)](https://code.google.com/p/bin2h/)[(d)](https://www.fourmilab.ch/xd/)[(e)](http://www.chami.com/tips/delphi/052098d.html)[(f)](https://code.google.com/p/bin2h/wiki/bin2h)[(g)](http://blog.theroyweb.com/embedding-a-binary-file-as-an-array-in-firmware)[(h)](https://github.com/tristan2468/Hexy)[(i)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hex_dump) to convert (possibly compressed) binary files into ".c" C language source code files as named arrays. (Typically using "const" or "PROGMEM" or whatever magic keyword your compiler uses to keep that data in flash, without using up any RAM). Then compile those source files into your application; and use normal array access [] to pull the bytes of the drawings or photographs from program memory.

There are a variety of tradeoffs in how to store stuff in flash, between

- drop drawings in PNG, photographs in JPEG, or both on the SD card in FAT format, and use a lot of code space on your microcontroller to implement FAT libraries, decompression from PNG or JPEG or both to RGB pixels, and reformat to push to your screen.
- Use software on your development computer to convert photographs or drawings or both into some other format that takes less code space (or less RAM) on your microcontroller -- in the extreme case, simply copy bytes from the SD card to the display.

There are a variety of lossy and lossless data compression libraries available; often the "decompression-only" section is relatively small and would probably fit on your microcontroller:

Libraries more-or-less specifically designed for photographs and drawings:

- [libpng and zlib source code](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngcode.html), and more [PNG documentation](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter13.html)
- [LodePNG](http://lodev.org/lodepng/)
- [TJpegDec](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/tjpgd/00index.html)

"Small" libraries that apparently work well in embedded systems:

- [miniLZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/) -- "one C source file and three header files. It compiles to less than 6 kB (on x86)"
- [Snappy in ANSI C](https://github.com/andikleen/snappy-c)
- [LibLZF](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/liblzf) consists of only two .c and two .h files in portable C.
- [LZW compression in 500 lines of C](http://zabkat.com/blog/24Jan10-lzw-compression-code.htm)
- more [open-source data compression example code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Compression/References)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it should be possible to adapt that library to your platform; it already lists Cortex-M0 so running it on an M3 or M4 should be fairly straightforward.

You'll have to weigh the tradeoff between an external storage device and using up on-chip flash - but if you have it available (the commonly encountered '407 variants have a lot) you can simplify your design by using it.  If you do a board you might want to place a footprint for an external flash device and not populate it if find you can squeeze everything on-chip.

Especially with the '407 if you are deploying test builds every few minutes during development you may find it worth the time to figure out how to configure your programmer tool to only erase and overwrite your program, and keep your data in a separate area of flash which you rewrite only when needed.

Comment: I have already tailored the TjpegDec on the MCU I'm looking for the way to put jpeg on the internal Flash (linker instructions, compiler settings and so on...). I will integrate an external FLASH in a bigger project when I have a lot of images, but in this case I would like to fit in the MCU flash. In both cases I would like to know what to say to IAR to put an image .jpeg file in flash.

Comment: Not sure how you'd do that under IAR (there are much better toolchains) but generally you can explore things like instructing the linker to include a binary, turning your binary into a hex file and flashing that separately or merging it with the one containing your code, or if all else fails translating your binary data to an array of hex bytes to initialize a constant array in C syntax, and feeding it through the compiler

Comment: @ChrisStratton  "translating your binary data to an array of hex bytes to initialize a constant array in C syntax" -- that's what I have done in the past, using simple RLE compression, and it worked out well.

Comment: @Chris What's wrong with IAR?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an external SPI flash device?  8MB (204 full screens) can be had in SOIC-8 for a couple of dollars and it's soldered down so won't have contact-reliability issues like an SD card.

If you can put the flash and OLED on separate SPI ports, you should be able to DMA between them at SPI bus-speed (1MB/sec = 25fps) via a tiny memory buffer.  I think the 407 would allow you to directly DMA from external flash via the FSMC to the OLED's SPI port (I've only used the F103 so haven't tried the FSMC, personally).

Much easier and probably better-performing than writing (de)compression code IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Open **[this link](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/file_to_hex.php?lang=en)**  **->** Upload your JPG(or JPEG)  file **->** Copy created Hex text **->** Create a **".h"** file with an array like this: *`const uint8_t image[] = {}`* **->** Put copied text inside **{}** **->** Include this file in your project.  ‌‌

Comment: This is not a good idea for many reasons. First of all, you don't put arrays that contain data into C headers. You would put them in C source files. But if you want to include a binary file into your build, why first convert it into text to have a C array, and then use a compiler to build it into binary object again? You can do that directly with objcopy already. And the question is not even how to include files but if it is possible to use JPG files instead of BMP so you are answering some other question than what was asked.

Comment: You are incorrect. It is common practice to include picture contents in an array defined within a ".h" file. Moreover, this comment consciously provides the correct solution to the question that was asked.

Comment: Sure, it may be common, but among who? Can you give an example, like hobbyists or professional software engineers? Even beginners quite quickly run into the rule that no data shall be emitted from simply including a C header file, so clearly the answer is against the philosophy of how to write good C. And I think the question is clear, is it possible to use JPGs instead of BMPs, it does not ask how to include them in the project. The correct way is to use objcopy on the binary file, not to route it through a website and put it into a **header** file. The question is also 9 years old already.

Comment: @Justme Could you please clarify how to do "You can do that directly with objcopy already" this?

Comment: There is a manual for objcopy and also many websites with examples how to do what you ask, and the exact details depend on a lot of details you did not provide, such as target platform and where you want the data to go (RAM, ROM), and what names your linker script uses for these sections.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use RLE encoding. It's lossless, very simple, and in my experience, will reduce the size of most images by half or more.
2. Reduce the color depth to 8 bits. If you use good software to downsample, it's unlikely you'll be able to tell the difference. DO NOT USE MS PAINT. I originally thought the color in my reduced images looked terrible, but it    turns out that MS PAINT just has a bad algorithm. Switching to irfan view resulted in images that look as good as the originals.
3. Reduce redundancy. Don't save a full frame image if you don't have to. If you can, assemble your screens from smaller images that can be re-used.

With that small display, I think you should be able to get by with just the above tricks.

Comment: This does not answer the 9-year old question if JPGs can be used instead of BMPs. It answers some other question.

Comment: @Justme X-Y fallacy imo. Plus, there's been 4 answers and 9 years already, so I'm hardly derailing the discussion. Don't ask me why this popped up in my list.